# PostgreSQL: select column and exclude from group

Tags: postgresql

This question has probably been asked in different formats, but I could not find the answer.

I have table `orders`

`date, quantity_ordered, unit_cost_cents  , product_model_number, title`

I would like to:

```
SELECT 
  model_number,
  title,
  SUM(unit_cost_cents  / 100.00 * quantity_ordered) as total
FROM orders
GROUP BY model_number
HAVING SUM(quantity_submitted) > 0
ORDER BY total DESC
```

But it requires grouping by the `title` as well.

My problem being is that my `title` changes over time. I'd like to preserve the titles and simply display/select the most recent `title` without grouping by title which would make the numbers different.

Comment: product_title looks functionally dependent on model_number, so it should not be here in the first place.

Comment: @wildplasser it mostly is, but the title changes over time so we keep track of those changes here. can you tell me how to get the most recent `title`?

Comment: No,I cannot. Can you define `most recent`?

Comment: if i have two orders; 1 from this month and 1 from last month. the most recent title is likely to be slighly different that the first. For this specific report i'd like to group the sales but show 1 title, either the first or most recent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to fetch the latest title:

```
SELECT 
  model_number,
  (select max(title) from orders where date = (
    select max(date) from orders where model_number = o.model_number)
  ) title,
  SUM(unit_cost_cents  / 100.00 * quantity_ordered) as total
FROM orders o
GROUP BY model_number 
HAVING SUM(quantity_submitted) > 0
ORDER BY total DESC
```

I used `select max(title)` instead of `select title` to make sure that the subquery will not return more than 1 rows (just in case).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  o.model_number
  , om.title
  , SUM(o.unit_cost_cents  / 100.00 * o.quantity_ordered) as total
FROM orders o
JOIN (SELECT model_number, title
        ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY model_number ORDER BY zdate DESC) AS rn
        FROM orders) om
  ON om.model_number=o.model_number AND om.rn=1
GROUP BY 1,2
HAVING SUM(o.quantity_submitted) > 0
ORDER BY 3 DESC
        ;
```